# excelsiorjet .exe flagging as virus for LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

past the month I have been working on a 2D game using LibGDX.
I have finished my game and created a runnable jar and the jar works just fine.

I wanted the game to work for users that does not have java installed, or for users that does not have the supported java version installed.

I have found the amazing solution and use [ExcelsiorJet](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/evaluate)

However, after compiling the sources and creating the installer, some people that download the installer, their Edge browser, and anti viruses (AVG mostly) flags it as a virus, and usually just deletes the downloaded temp file **immeditaly** before they can open it, even if *I wrap it in a zip*.

I have virus scanned it on this [online scanner](https://www.virustotal.com/) and it showed as **Safe** on all anti viruses it described.

I don't really see any reason for this to be flagged as a virus, and it makes me look not trustworthy for the people I want to share the game with.

I have them to download it from there: http://benberi.me/obsidio/download/installer/Obsidio-Installer.exe

Have anyone been having troubles with Libgdx sources being flagged as a virus?

Answer (score 0):

Not all virus scanners can detect all viruses. It is possible that the program you are using actually is infected with a virus, and Edge and AVG are accurately detecting that. It is also possible that there is no virus, and something in the file is producing false positives.

Sometimes legitimate software products get hijacked and bad guys inject malware into them without the software developers realizing this has happened. Some examples of this:

- [Some official downloads of Phpmyadmin were found to contain malware.](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/09/27/sourceforge-serves-up-malware-infected-phpmyadmin-toolkit/)
- [Official downloads of Transmission torrent client for Mac OSX were found to contain malware.](https://torrentfreak.com/attackers-infect-transmission-torrent-client-with-os-x-malware-160831/)
- [Linux Mint official ISOs were infected with malware](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/02/22/worlds-biggest-linux-distro-infected-with-malware/)
- [CCleaner official downloads were found to contain malware](https://www.wired.com/story/ccleaner-malware-supply-chain-software-security/)

If the program you have used to bundle your game is really a legitimate and trustworthy product, then you should be able to contact the developers and bring this problem to their attention. They will look into what is causing the problem and fix it. Until they resolve this issue, there is not much else you can do to prevent your game bundle from triggering certain virus scanners.

That said, I would suggest that you stop asking people to download and run your game until you find a way to fix this problem (either by reaching out to the developers or by finding a different distribution solution). The truth is that you don't know why it is causing virus warnings, and you are not really sure that it does not actually contain a virus. You are asking other people to download your game and trust the installer even though their virus scanner is warning them, and you don't really know if the program you used is really safe. This is a very bad practice.

(Side note: Compressing your files inside of a zip does not prevent anti-virus programs from scanning the file. If it did, think of how dangerous it would be to download any zip files ever. Virus scanners look inside the compressed file and scan the contents.)

Answer (score 0):

Excelsior guy here, with one possible explanation.

Excelsior JET relies on the public domain [LZMA SDK](http://7-zip.org/sdk.html) to minimize the size of the resulting installers. Sadly, many virus writers also appreciate the compression rate delivered by LZMA, so the presence of LZMA code may [trigger a false alarm](https://www.excelsior-usa.com/blog/excelsior-jet/false-positive-virus-detection/)

We do submit our product to major anti-virus software vendors for white-listing, so a malware database update often solves the problem. As a workaround, you can try to switch to fast compression, which does not use LZMA, or use a third-party setup generator. A couple of free ones are [NSIS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/) (makes EXE) and [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) (makes MSI).

If this does not help, please [contact our technical support](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/#contact).